# preg_replace to delete something in a special string

Tags: php, preg-replace

Hi I tried to delete something in a string. But I don't know ho to make it.

My string: `@trash='﻿test1',value1='test2',@trash='test3',value2='test4'`

I want to delete all with @trash for example = `@trash='﻿test1',`.
Perhaps important is, that of course the value in the example above "test1" is allways changing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following codes

```
echo preg_replace("/@trash='(.*?)',/", "", $string);
```

#### output

```
value1='test2',value2='test4'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace("#@trash='[\w.]+',#","",$string);
```

should work fine

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to preg_replace to do it :

```
$array = explode (',', $my_string);
$new_array = array ();
foreach ($array as $element)
{
    if (strpos ($element, '@') !== false) // OR if ($element[0] !== '@'), it depends the format of your string
        $new_array[] = $element;
}
$new_string = implode (',', $new_array);
```

preg_replace (And anything using REG EXP) is long as hell, avoid it when possible.

Comment: `$array = explode (",",$my_string);`

Comment: I believed this too at one point, but running some bench tests proved me wrong.  Run this 1M times and compare it to the `preg_replace` method run 1M times.  I have a feeling `preg_replace` will be faster.

Comment: @steven Thanks you for notifying

Comment: @SeanBright In fact, it depends the REG EXP. Anyway, I added something using the fact the @ char seems to be always the first element, making it way faster than strpos and preg_replace